# Apache (httpd) VirtualHost RewriteCond Variables not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, mod-rewrite, virtualhost, apache-2.4

I am trying to make a dynamic virtual host entry with the intent of redirecting all traffic to *.mydomain.com to /var/www/html/*  this part works but I also what a Rewrite conditions that checks if the directory exists if it does not then I want to redirect all traffic to the root /var/www/html/index.php.

This part is not working because the during my testing I noticed that none of the Rewrite variables are working they are are blank and I cannot figure out why here is my virtual host configuration

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
# LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
LogFormat "%{Host}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName vhosts.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/html/%1

    RewriteEngine on
    LogLevel warn rewrite:trace4

    # If the request is not for a valid directory
    RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # If the request is not for a valid file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # If the request is not for a valid link
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* /var/www/html/index.php

</VirtualHost>
```

You will notice that I have several uses of the variable that I can use when testing and looking at my log file this

```
[Wed Jul 29 16:56:56.015818 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 23898] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:4863] xx.xx.xx.xx - - [fake.mydomain.com/sid#7f5c89bcf570][rid#7f5c89ed5000/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[Wed Jul 29 16:56:56.016050 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 23898] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:4863] xx.xx.xx.xx - - [fake.mydomain.com/sid#7f5c89bcf570][rid#7f5c89ed5000/initial] applying pattern '.*' to uri '/'
[Wed Jul 29 16:56:56.018361 2015] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 23898] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:4863] xx.xx.xx.xx - - [fake.mydomain.com/sid#7f5c89bcf570][rid#7f5c89ed5000/initial] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
[Wed Jul 29 16:56:56.018411 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 23898] mod_rewrite.c(475): [client xx.xx.xx.xx:4863] xx.xx.xx.xx - - [fake.mydomain.com/sid#7f5c89bcf570][rid#7f5c89ed5000/initial] pass through /
```

even though %1 passes for the virtual directory just fine it does not work in the mod rewrite rule. All other uses of the variables yield the same results any help would be appreciated.

Not sure it makes a difference but this is running in AWS on Amazon Linux build.

Comment: %1 is NOT a kind of a global variable for the whole Apache config. In [VirtualDocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol) it corresponds to the first part of the 'Host' name, and in RewriteCond or RewriteRule it represents backreferences to the preceding RewriteCond capturing groups. See Apache doc for [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: then why doesn't %{REQUEST_FILENAME} return any value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%1 is NOT a kind of a global variable for the whole Apache config.

In [VirtualDocumentRoot](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) it corresponds to the first part of the 'Host' name, and in `RewriteCond` or `RewriteRule` it represents backreferences to the capturing groups in the *preceding* `RewriteCond` . See Apache doc for [RewriteCond](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Throw away that part :

```
RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 !-d
```

Your use of %1 is wrong, you do not have any RewriteCond before, so %1 is empty string. So basically you have a condition that states "If /var/www/html/ is not a directory, do ..."

But obviously `/var/www/html` is a directory, that's why your log line says

`RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched`

**UPADTE** as follow up from your comment :

The thing to understand is that Apache is made of many different pieces which are the modules. Each module comes with its own syntax. This makes the whole very powerful, but can be confusing, as in your question. Each module could define a syntax with a variable called `%1` representing some thing else in each module.

It could be that I've now better understood what you want to do :

1. Check if a request has a directory corresponding to its subdomain, if not, send to `/var/www/html/nosubdomain.php`
2. Else check if request corresponds to a file/directory/link, if not, send to `/var/www/html/nofile.php`

*Step 1 : Get the subdomain*

To get the subdomain, you can use the ability of mod_rewrite to define and to set environment variables (here the `%1` is the result of the capture in RewriteCond):

```
# Setting environment variable SUBDOMAIN = (subdomain).example.com

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=SUBDOMAIN:%1]
```

*Step 2 : Now you can use the SUBDOMAIN variable in your rewrite rules/cond and check if the directory corresponding to the subdomain exists. If not you redirect to the defined page*

```
# Test if subdomain directory exists, if not, redirect to a 
# standard page (/var/www/html/nosubdomain.php).

RewriteCond /var/www/html/%{ENV:SUBDOMAIN} !-d
RewriteRule .* /var/www/html/nosubdomain.php [L]
```

*Step 3 : check if requested file exists, if not, send a standard page (`/var/www/html/nofile.php`). For this it’s far better to rely on Apache checking itself and use an ErrorDocument. We need an Alias because you want the file `nofile.php` to be outside the VirtualDocumentRoot (`/var/www/html/subdomain/`)*

```
Alias /nofile.php /var/www/html/nofile.php
ErrorDocument 404 /nofile.php
```

Putting all those steps together just after your directive `RewriteEngine On` should bring you up with a working setup, that of course you will have to adapt to your exact use case. I've tested this setup, it works as I wanted it to, but on a Apache 2.2.

You could also combine the step 1 and 2 together if you do not use SUBDOMAIN in another place :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]*)\.example\.com$
RewriteCond /var/www/html/%1 !-d
RewriteRule .* /var/www/html/nosubdomain.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you for your response and I believe I follow your statement. So although %1 is a variable usable for dynamic VirtualDocumentRoot it is not accessible for the RewriteCond.

With this information in mind then how would I construct a RewriteCond that would check if a the VirtualDocumentRoot path exist (In my case this is made up of the sub domain plus my base path)  since the %1 variable is not available here.